# Error with ddply: arguments imply different number of rows

Tags: r, plyr

Hi I am working on the following dataframe(`nows` = 62208):

`> head(workfile)
                      V1       V5           V7  V8        V9
4309 2014-03-01 13:30:00 1582.899 D.1Elec-0001 D.1 Elec-0001
6801 2014-03-01 13:45:00 1582.900 D.1Elec-0001 D.1 Elec-0001
6805 2014-03-01 14:00:00 1582.919 D.1Elec-0001 D.1 Elec-0001
5710 2014-03-01 14:15:00 1582.939 D.1Elec-0001 D.1 Elec-0001
5714 2014-03-01 14:30:00 1582.944 D.1Elec-0001 D.1 Elec-0001
6814 2014-03-01 14:45:00 1582.945 D.1Elec-0001 D.1 Elec-0001`

I would like to compute the differences between each element in column (`V5`) and its previous one inserted in the same column (`V5`) but in a previous  row. In column `V7` I have 72 different levels (in my case 72 different rooms).

If I use this code:
`pippo<-ddply(workfile, .(V7), transform, diff = c(tail(V5,-1)-head(V5,-1)), NA)`
it occurs the following error message:
`Error in data.frame(list(V1 = c(1393680600, 1393681500, 1393682400, 1393683300,:
 arguments imply differing number of rows: 864, 863, 1`

If I use this  code:
`pippo<-ddply(workfile, .(V7), transform, diff = c(tail(workfile$V5,-1)-head(workfile$V5,-1)), NA)`
it occours this other error message:
`Error in data.frame(list(V1 = c(1393680600, 1393681500, 1393682400, 1393683300,:  arguments imply differing number of rows: 864, 62207, 1`

I cannot `dput` my dataframe because it is very big.

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: A `dput` should not be a problem, you can use for example `dput(head(workfile, 20))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is just the simple differences, this should work fine (you can substitute `0` for `NA` if you want):

```
pippo <- ddply(df, .(V7), transform, diff = c(0,diff(V5)))
```

You should also check `dplyr`, it should be faster with big data.frames:

```
library(dplyr)
pippo<- df%.%group_by(V7)%.%mutate(diff=c(NA, diff(V5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an easy solution:

```
workfile$diff <- c(NA,diff(workfile$V5))
```

Comment: Yes I tried with something like that but it is no ok to me because it does not split the results by each different variable of column `V7`